# calling a private method by a return statement java

Tags: java

So I'm new to java and I'm trying to wrap my head around this. So far I'm writing a public method that calls a private method, both of which are written in the same class. When testing the public method, I am able to call the public method against an object, employeeOne, whose parameters are supplied by the user. I'm not exactly sure whats going on with the private method call here though since it appears that I'm calling it on the class (i think) and not the objects with defined attributes.

So here is a private method that I have written inside a class called Employee:

```
private static double computeGrossPay()
{
    if (hoursWorked <= 40)
    {
        grossPay = (hoursWorked * payRate);
    }
    else if (hoursWorked >= 40)
    {
        grossPay = ((40 * payRate) + ((1.5 * payRate) * (hoursWorked - 40)));
    }
    return grossPay;
}
```

I was trying to figure out a way to call this method in another class and obviously since it is a private method I can't call it anywhere outside of the class it is written in. So I wrote a public method that makes a call to the private method

```
public double grossPayDisplay()
{
    return Employee.computeGrossPay();
}
```

This is where my question comes into play: So far this code works but I'm not entirely clear on *why* it works.

Here is how I tested it:

```
System.out.println(employeeOne.grossPayDisplay());
```

employeeOne is an object created from the class Employee whose parameters are supplied by the user, my question is:

How does the compiler go from Employee in Employee.computeGrossPay() to employeeOne?

Or to reiterate how does

```
return Employee.computeGrossPay()
```

actually pass attributes to computeGrossPay()?

Comment: If you make a public method and all it does is call a private method, why don't you just make the private method public?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`computeGrossPay` is a static method, which means it belongs to the class itself, rather an any particular `Employee` object. Static methods can only access other static members, so it looks like your fields like `hoursWorked` must be static too.

This "works" but it doesn't seem correct to me. A field like `hoursWorked` is an attribute that should belong to each individual `Employee` - try removing `static` from that field's declaration.

Now, you'll probably get a compile error, since `computeGrossPay` is trying to access an instance (non-static) field when that method isn't being called on an instance of `Employee`. For this reason `computeGrossPay` should probably be an instance method:

```
private double computeGrossPay() { ... }
```

And then it would be called like this:

```
public double grossPayDisplay()
{
    return this.computeGrossPay();
}
```

(which makes `grossPayDisplay` look a little pointless - you could just make `computeGrossPay` public)

Alternatively, `computeGrossPay` could stay static and take an `Employee` as an argument:

```
private static double computeGrossPay(Employee employee)
{
    if (employee.hoursWorked <= 40)
    {
        employee.grossPay = (employee.hoursWorked * payRate);
    } else if (hoursWorked >= 40)
    {
        employee.grossPay = ((40 * payRate) + ((1.5 * payRate) * (employee.hoursWorked - 40)));
    }
    return employee.grossPay;
}
```

But that's pretty ugly and doesn't make as much sense.

Above, I just assumed `grossPay` was also made an instance field too - but it feels a little strange how it's being used. Since gross pay is something being calculated on the fly, it doesn't seem like that should be saved in a field. Consider making it a local variable within the method:

```
private double computeGrossPay()
{
    double grossPay; //declare the local variable

    //assign it depending on hoursWorked
    if (hoursWorked <= 40)
    {
        grossPay = (hoursWorked * payRate);
    }
    else
    {
        grossPay = ((40 * payRate) + ((1.5 * payRate) * (hoursWorked - 40)));
    }

    //return its value
    return grossPay;
}
```

(doesn't matter whether the method is static or not for that last point)

One last note: you'll notice I kept treating `payRate` like a static field. I just did that as an example, but it seems like it could go either way: there could be a single pay rate for all employees, or each employee could have their own pay rate. That just depends on the context of your program and it's up to you.

Comment: That "Alternatively, ..." part, though technically correct, is hideous.  `computeGrossPay` probably shouldn't be static *at all* -- there's not really a good reason for it not to be an instance method, particularly since it's mucking around with instance fields.  Good to mention the possibility, but you shouldn't ever really *do* things that way.  :)

Comment: @cHao Agreed, just wanted to cover the basics. I added a note about that making less sense in this example.

Comment: It would definitely be easier to use it as a public method. After reading up on different access modifiers I was interested to know exactly how (or in this case if) the private method could be called from a method in a separate .java file. I guess it gets the job done, but I definitely wouldn't bet my payroll on it!

Comment: @user1822526 If all a public method does is call a private method (with the same arguments at least), then it really does seem like the private method should just be public. Private methods are typically "helpers" that do internal logic or other special things, which shouldn't be exposed as the "public interface".

Comment: Why do you put `this.` in front of a method invocation? What does it signify?

Comment: @SteveKuo `this` just points to "this object" in instance context. I just used it there to highlight the fact that I had switched from static context. It could be ommitted. `this` is more often used for disambiguation, like when a field and method parameter have the same name.

Comment: @PaulBellora But in the case of a method it disambiguates nothing, as the method could a static or non-static method. ie, `this.someStaticMethod()` is still valid.

Comment: @SteveKuo You're absolutely right - though calling a static method through an instance will generally show a warning. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that the compiler goes from employee to employeeone. Your private method is declared as static, and therefore the variables that it references are (by the definition of static) common to any member of that class.

Are your hoursWorked, grossPay, and payRate variables declared globally, because if they are then it makes no sense in having objects of that class if they all reference the same variables.